# Android Coroutines and LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to know if the code I have to use Coroutines and LiveData on an Android application is correct or if there is something wrong with it.

Take as an example an UserProfile fragment and an EditUserBio fragment. I have a UserProfileViewModel scoped to these 2 fragments.

My UserProfileViewModel is something like:

```
class UserProfileViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val loading: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _loading

    private val _errorMessage = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val errorMessage: LiveData<String> get() = _errorMessage
    
    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val user: LiveData<User> get() = _user
...
}
```

In both UserProfileFragment and EditUserBioFragment I observe `loading` and `errorMessage` LiveData events to show a loading dialog and an error message.

In EditUserBioFragment I want to be able to tap on a button, do a network call to update user profile, update cached User and then go back to UserProfileFragment.

From my understanding of [Use Kotlin coroutines with Architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) and cortoutines [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) I can do something like:

```
viewModel.updateBio(data).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    Navigation.findNavController(v).popBackStack()
})
```

and my UserProfileViewModel implementation would be something like

```
fun updateBio(profile: UserProfileModel) = liveData {
    withContext(viewModelScope.coroutineContext) {
        _loading.postValue(true)
        try {
            /* suspend*/ userRepository.updateProfile(profile)
            emit(Void.TYPE)
        } catch (e : Exception) {
            _errorMessage.postValue(e.localizedMessage)
        } finally {
            _loading.postValue(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a correct usage?

If `userRepository.updateProfile(profile)` throws are there any problems in:

1. not calling `emit`?
2. or calling `viewModel.updateBio(data).observe(` multiple times?

Comment: Not that Kotlin coroutines has StateFlow and SharedFlow, there's not much reason to mix and match between coroutines and LiveData, which results in more complicated code than if you just picked one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [coroutines best practices by Google](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices).

I would not do (from a UI/Fragment/Activity) `viewModel.someOperation(xxx).observe(...)` all the time, I think it makes the code harder to follow. You have all these LiveData exposed and have to make sure things happen in the correct stream.

I would instead do with one (or maybe two if you want to split "navigation") state:

```
viewModel.state.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { state ->
            when (state) {
              is X -> ...
              is Y -> ...
```

you get the idea.

In your VM, "state" is what you guessed:

```
    private val _state = MutableLiveData<SomeState>(SomeState.DefaultState)
    val state: LiveData<SomeState> = _state
```

This has decoupled the UI (Fragment/Act) from the logic of having to deal with a coroutine, a response, etc. Instead, you now do all that inside your ViewModel, which will go the "extra mile" of checking what happened, and emitting a sensible/opinionated "SomeState" that the fragment can react to.

So your updateBio fun becomes more..

```
fun updateBio(profile: UserProfileModel) {
     viewModelScope.launch {
         _state.postValue(SomeState.Loading)

         // here call your useCase/Repo/etc. which is suspend.
         // evaluate the response, wait for it, do what it takes, and .postValue(SomeState.XXX) based on your logic.
```

Now `userRepository.updateProfile(profile)` could return a concrete type, like returns the newly updated Profile directly or it could expose a `sealed class UserProfileState {}` with various "states" so the ViewModel would:

```
sealed class UserProfileState {
   data class UpdatedOk(val profile: UserProfileModel) : UserProfileState()
   data class Failure(val exception: Exception) : UserProfileState()
}
```

And you'd then...

```
when (val response = userRepo.update(profile)) {
    is UserProfileState.UpdatedOk -> _state.postValue(SomeState.Updated(response.profile))
    is Failure -> //deal with it
}
```

I hope you get the idea. In the end, if the userProfile fails to update the bio, if you use a "UserProfileState" you can signal with `.Failure`. Or if it just returns a "UserProfileModel" you have to decide if you want to raise an exception or return Null and have the ViewModel decide what to do. It really depends what kind of interaction you need.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my follow up question is: I want to show a loading dialog while doing the update, should I use another LiveData to show/hide it? Because being a scoped VM both fragments would receive the show/hide events.

Comment: If only one fragment is visible at the time, you could `state.post(SomeState.Loading)` as the first thing you do before starting the work in the updateBio function. `viewModelScope.launch { _state.post(Loading) ... then do the rest }`

Comment: The problem I encounter was doing 2 post one after another `_state.post(LoadingOff); _state.post(UpdateOk)`. The `LoadingOff` was not received

Comment: You can do `_state.value = Loading` (you may need to do this outside of the `launch` I can't remember,  but that's fine).  Then do your thing, then `_state.post(UpdateOk)` when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I did find an issue with the ViewModel being scoped.

I end up creating a

```
sealed class LiveDataResult<out R> {
    data class Loading(val show: Boolean) : LiveDataResult<Nothing>()
    data class Result<out T>(val value: T) : LiveDataResult<T>()
    data class Error(val message: String?) : LiveDataResult<Nothing>()
}
```

and changing `updateBio` to emit LiveDataResult

```
fun updateBio(profile: UpdateProfileRequestModel) = liveData {
    withContext(viewModelScope.coroutineContext) {
        emit(LiveDataResult.Loading(true))
        try {
            userRepository.updateProfile(profile)
            emit(LiveDataResult.Result(true))
        } catch (e : Exception) {
            emit(LiveDataResult.Error(e.localizedMessage))
        } finally {
            emit(LiveDataResult.Loading(false))
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this is a better solution than single `val loading: LiveData<Boolean>` and `val errorMessage: LiveData<String>` for multiple calls.